# Minimum cover for sets in which each element appears in exactly 2 sets?

Tags: linear-programming, np

Is there an algorithm for finding minimal covers of a set of sets in which each element of the universe appears in exactly 2 sets? I realize that LP relaxation approximates this to within a factor of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the well-known problem of [Minimum Vertex Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover). It is conjectured to be NP-hard to approximate within $2-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. Many $2$-approximation algorithms exist.

Comment: I believe The minimum vertex cover problem is equivalent to the maximum clique problem.

Comment: Not in terms of approximability. Vertex cover is much easier. Maximum clique cannot be approximated to within $O(n^{1-\epsilon})$.

Comment: Has this been proven or is this simply the best current approximation?

Comment: Because I believe I have found an n^2 running time transformation from the maximum clique problem to the Vertex Cover Problem.

Comment: Woah, never mind. Apparently, unless P = NP, there is no approximation algorithm better than O(n^(1−ϵ))

Comment: Time to recheck my work.

Comment: Can you explain the O(n^(1−ϵ)) limit to approximation? Isn't the vertex cover still going to be off by n since it is off by 2* the size of the best solution?

Comment: And the best solution likely scales with n?

Comment: Ok, I got it. I looked it all up, and yeah, the two are equivalent, but as you say, they are not equivalent in terms of approximability.